# How can I cluster my weighted directed graph?

Tags: machine-learning, graph, data-science, cluster-analysis, random-walk

I've been trying to cluster my graph of jobs.

The edges weights are the count of the transitions between 2 nodes(jobs).

I've been reading about and I've based my code in this paper: https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01887680/document

Code:

```
G = nx.DiGraph() #Full transitions graph
G.add_weighted_edges_from(list(transitions_df.itertuples(index=False, name=None)))

H = nx.subgraph(G, list(df.query("sub_family_desc == 'ClientSupport' | sub_family_desc == 'Consulting' ").code.unique())) #Gruph with only two subfamily_jobs(clusters)
pos = nx.kamada_kawai_layout(H)
weights = nx.get_edge_attributes(H, "weight")

a = nx.spectral_graph_forge(H, 0.7)
adj_mat = nx.to_numpy_matrix(a)
sc = SpectralClustering(2, affinity='precomputed', n_init=100,assign_labels="kmeans",random_state=np.random.seed(1234))
sc.fit(adj_mat)
```

I also tryed to add random walks, but I have faild and couldn't pass the random walk to the SKlean Spectral Cluster

```
from stellargraph import StellarGraph

#converting it to stellar graph format so we can leverage biased random walk from this library
sg_graph = StellarGraph.from_networkx(H)
print(sg_graph.info())

from stellargraph.data import BiasedRandomWalk
from gensim.models import Word2Vec

#from each singular node/job we generate 40 biased (weight-biased) random walks with a max length of 10
rw = BiasedRandomWalk(sg_graph)
#40 sequences per node
weighted_walks = rw.run(nodes=sg_graph.nodes(),length=10, n=100, p=5, q=0.05, weighted=True, seed=1234)
print("Number of random walks: {}".format(len(weighted_walks)))
```

Should I have added the random_walk in the model? How can I make it?

Comment: Did you read the description of the "graph" tag before you added it to this question?

Answer (score 0):

Use [louvain community detection](https://networkx.org/documentation/latest/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.community.louvain.louvain_partitions.html).